# How to notify when user hand off back inkwell onLongPress?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a InkWell which I want when user press it (onLongPress) , execute some seeking in audio , but as you know onLongPress will fire only once.

for example I want if user hold it foe 2 seconds , I fire that 4 times (every 500 mililliseconds of holding , seek some duration ).
what I implement for onLongPress is below :

```
_timer = Timer.periodic(
  const Duration(seconds: 2),
  (Timer timer) {
                   // seek operation
                }
```

but my problem is that how can I notify when user hand off back the button ?
it is necessary to cancel the _timer , because if we don't cancel this , the seek operation function will execute for ever .

Comment: make your `InkWell` as a child of `GestureDetector` - that way you will have callbacks you want from `GestureDetector` and splashes from `InkWell`

Comment: it doesn't work , the logic is true but in action it doesn't work

Comment: yes it works - i verified that 5 minutes ago: `Container(
            height: 200,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onLongPress: () => print('press'),
              onLongPressUp: () => print('press end'),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                splashColor: Colors.orange,
              ),
            ),
          )`

Comment: yes , you are true , my problem was that I register onTap into GestureDetector . Thanks .

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: I will accept your answer as true if you post it

Comment: but honestly that `InkWell` will make your users confused as the splash is misleading - it does not mean that long press occurred - i would not do that that way

Comment: yes , is there any way to solve that ?

Comment: sure but it is not easy: you need to create `InkRipple` or `InkSplash` inside `GestureDetector`

Comment: something like `LongPressRipple` here: https://pastebin.com/raw/k0pecW2Y

Comment: yes , thanks , Mr pskink

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `onLongPressUp` event of [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) to detect when longPressed is released,

```
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => print('tapped!'),
          onLongPressUp: (){
            //long press released
          },
        ),
```

Comment: thanks in onLongPressUp we can cancle it.but the reason I use inkWell was for it's highLightColor , borderRadius and splashColor , how can I implement them using GestutrDetector ?

Comment: You can have inkwell or Flatbutton as a child of GestureDetector if that serves your purpose. although it does not look nice.